# How to add a standard value to a field that uses a query with a relative path?

Tags: field

I have a Sitecore solution that has several website folders. Each of these sites has its own Settings/Enumerations.

On my templates, the fields are configured to use a query with a relative path as the source, to select the enumeration items from the current website: `query:$site/Site Settings/Enumerations/Orientation/*`

I need to add a standard value, and I'm not sure how to do that. I copied in the ID of one of my enumeration items into the standard value, and it technically works but then it's using one site's item in all places instead of using the item that belongs to the current site; if I look at that field on an item in one of my other sites, it shows "The field contains a value that is not in the selection list" because the default item is not included in the query results. Ideally the standard value would be the equivalent of `$site/Site Settings/Enumerations/Orientation/Left`. Is there any way to do this without writing some kind of complex custom processor?

Comment: If your aim is to automatically select all items in let's say multilist field that belongs to a specific site on your standard values, then I am afraid you will need some custom processor or field.

Comment: I found the solution in creating a custom processor to expand tokens, which is documented here https://sitecorecorner.com/2014/08/03/sitecore-custom-tokens/